# What's the difference between length function and distance function in Unity Shader?

Tags: unity, shaders

I'm confused about the two functions, do they return the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length()` takes in one vector and returns the magnitude of that.

`distance()` takes in two and returns the distance between those. Basically, `distance(a, b)` is the same as `length(a - b)`

Comment: Will it be different in some cases?

Comment: @OtakuFitness No, both are mathematically equivalent. The former is probably implemented as the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Distance is the length between **two** vectors.
Length is the magnitude of **one** vector.